# Linear algebra library for the D programming language

Tags: matrix, d, linear-algebra, mathematical-optimization

I'm looking for a package to do matrix math with matrices of up to about 100 x 100.

I need to, at a minimum, do inverses, multiplication and transposition. I'd prefer a more encapsulated interface over higher performance.

Comment: Is there any thing in the usuall place that suits your needs. I didn't answer this because I think you've probably tried there. http://dsource.org/projects

Comment: I know there are a few linear algebra libs in there. What I don't know is how done they are. I'm sort of looking for "I've used X and it was good" answers.

Answer (score 4):

dsource.org/projects has been mentioned on this thread before, here are a few details.

Here are the [D language bindings for the GNU Scientific Library (GSL)](http://www.dsource.org/projects/bindings/wiki/GnuScientificLibrary).

Here is a link to [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/).

Here is some links to the documentation on [BLAS support](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/BLAS-Support.html), decompositions ([1](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Vectors-and-Matrices.html), [2](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Linear-Algebra.html)), [eigenssystems](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Eigensystems.html), in GSL.

Answer (score 2):

Can't D make direct calls into C code?  Or are you looking for a library written in D?

Comment: C can't overload operators, and linking D and C++ is "non-trivial". A simple wrapper around lampack or whatever would be good but I want to do multiplication with code like "Matrix x = y*z;